# Is it safe to capture properties of `self` without capturing `self`?

Tags: swift

You can copy this playground verbatim:

```
var closures=[() -> Void]()
class Thing {
    let name: String
    init(_ name: String) { self.name=name }
}
class RefThingWrapper {
    let thing: Thing
    init(_ t: Thing) {
        self.thing=t
        closures.append { [thing, weak self] in   // Even though `thing` captured strongly, `self` could still get deallocated.
            print((self == nil) ? "`self` deallocated" : "`self` not deallocated")
            print(thing.name)   // Decided to use `thing` within closure to eliminate any chance of optimizations affecting the test results — which I found when I captured `self` strongly without using it.
        }
    }
}
struct ValThingWrapper {
    let thing: Thing
    init(_ t: Thing) {
        self.thing=t
        closures.append { [weak thing] in
            print((thing == nil) ? "`thing` deallocated" : "`thing` not deallocated")
        }
    }
}

var wrapper=Optional(RefThingWrapper(Thing("Thing 1")))   // Test with reference type.
//var wrapper=Optional(ValThingWrapper(Thing("Thing 1")))   // Test with value type.
closures[0]()
wrapper=nil
closures[0]()
```

It demonstrates how a property of `self` — whether `self` is a reference or value type — can be captured within a closure independently of `self`. Running the program as is demonstrates a captured property existing after `self` has been deallocated. Testing with the value type wrapper demonstrates that, if weakly captured, the instance will be deallocated once the referencing value instance is deallocated.

I wasn't sure this was possible because when creating the closure at first, I forgot to initialize the property I was capturing. So the compiler complained — in the capture list — `'self' used before all stored properties are initialized`. So I figured `self` was being captured implicitly, and only after digging deeper discovered otherwise.

Is this documented somewhere? I found [this post](https://forums.swift.org/t/proposal-closures-capture-weak-by-default/338/3) by Joe Groff where he proposes:

> For 'let' properties of classes, it'd be reasonable to propose having
>   closures capture the *property* directly by default in this way
>   instead of capturing 'self' (and possibly allowing referencing them
>   without 'self.', since 'self' wouldn't be involved in any cycle formed
>   this way).

This was back in 2015, and I didn't find any implemented proposals that arose from the discussion. Is there any authoritative source that communicates this behavior?

Comment: Yes, the ability to precapture a value into the capture list is little known. Note that this is not the same as closure-capturing; in fact, it is the opposite, it is a way to avoid closure-capturing.

Comment: Take a look at this example where I use this: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch26p878undoableDrag4/ch39p1123undoableDrag/MyView.swift See line 41. If we didn’t precapture we’d be doing exactly the opposite of what I’m trying to do. We want to capture the value of `self.center` as it is _now_, not the value it will have when this closure is _called_.

Comment: @matt Wow. Don't recall seeing an assignment take place in a capture list before. Looking at the syntax, precapturing a value type looks roughly how I would've imagined it to. With reference types and absent the `=` sign, whether `self` is captured implicitly seems ambiguous to me. But in hindsight it only seems natural that if you can capture a value type without capturing `self` along with it, the same would follow for reference types as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re just asking for documentation on capture lists and reference types, see *The Swift Programming Language* [Resolving Strong Reference Cycles for Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID57). Also see the [Language Reference: Capture Lists](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID544)

- If your capture list includes value type, you’re getting copy of the value.

  ```
  var foo = 1

  let closure = { [foo] in
      print(foo)
  }

  foo = 42

  closure() // 1; capturing value of `foo` as it was when the closure was declared
  ```
- If your capture list includes a reference type, you’re getting a copy of the reference to that current instance.

  ```
  class Bar {
      var value: Int

      init(value: Int) { self.value = value }
  }

  var bar = Bar(value: 1)

  let closure = { [bar] in
      print(bar.value)
  }

  bar.value = 2

  bar = Bar(value: 3)

  closure() // 2; capturing reference to first instance that was subsequently updated
  ```

  These captured references are strong by default, but can optionally be marked as `weak` or `unowned`, as needed, too.
- That [Capture Lists](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID544) document outlines the way that you can capture a property without capturing `self`:

  > You can also bind an arbitrary expression to a named value in a capture list. The expression is evaluated when the closure is created, and the value is captured with the specified strength. For example:
  >
  > ```
  > // Weak capture of "self.parent" as "parent"
  > myFunction { [weak parent = self.parent] in print(parent!.title) }
  > ```

  I’m not crazy about their code sample, but it illustrates the capture of a property without capturing `self`, nonetheless.